# how to use drag and drop on recycler view using firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to implement the drag and drop feature to firebase recycler view. There is not enough information in the docs for this implementation. Im assuming i have to use onchildmoved for the event listener but i do not know how to reorder the data.

Comment: There is very little related to Firebase when it comes to drag-and-drop. If you already have drag-and-drop working in a non-Firebase recycler view, it should not be too difficult to add the Firebase parts. Do you already have the non-Firebase parts working? If so, seeing that would make this question a lot more concrete.

Comment: yes i do have it working but when doing the drag and drop there is a an arraylist attach to it which i then have to swap all other items one spot down. when it comes to firebase i only receive a snapshot and i dont know how to change the order of the list associated with firebase database.

Comment: Can you reduce the code you have to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem. Such an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it a lot more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this and have done the following (assuming you are using a class which extends `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` e.g. `RecyclerViewTouchHelper`):

1) Add a property to your Firebase child to record its order in the list (e.g. `orderNumber`).

2) Modify the `onMove()` method of your `RecyclerViewTouchHelper` to include the following:

```java
@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

    final int firstPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    final int secondPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
    DatabaseReference firstItemRef = mMovieAdapter.getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    DatabaseReference secondItemRef = mMovieAdapter.getRef(target.getAdapterPosition());

    HashMap<String, Object> updateFirstItemOrderNumber = new HashMap<>();
    updateFirstItemOrderNumber.put("orderNumber", secondPosition);
    firstItemRef.updateChildren(updateFirstItemOrderNumber);

    HashMap<String, Object> updateSecondItemOrderNumber = new HashMap<>();
    updateSecondItemOrderNumber.put("orderNumber", firstPosition);
    secondItemRef.updateChildren(updateSecondItemOrderNumber);

    return false;
}
```

3) When creating your `RecyclerViewAdapter`, make sure that the query you use is ordered by `orderNumber` e.g.

```java
Query orderedListQuery = FirebaseRef.orderByChild("orderNumber");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had quite a bit of confusion trying to get this to work for myself on Firebase UI 3.1.0. Here's my final working solution (explanation below):

```kotlin
// overrides from ItemTouchHelper
override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
    val fromPos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    val toPos = target.adapterPosition

    val fromSnapshot = snapshots.first { it.order == fromPos }
    val toSnapshot = snapshots.first { it.order == toPos }

    Logger.d("Habit ${fromSnapshot.name} (${fromSnapshot.order}) to $toPos")
    Logger.d("Habit ${toSnapshot.name} (${toSnapshot.order}) to $fromPos")
    fromSnapshot.order = toPos
    toSnapshot.order = fromPos

    hasDragged = true

    notifyItemMoved(toPos, fromPos)
    return true
}
```

```kotlin
// overrides from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
override fun onChildChanged(type: ChangeEventType?, snapshot: DataSnapshot?, newIndex: Int, oldIndex: Int) {
    when (type) {
        ChangeEventType.MOVED -> if (!hasDragged) {
            super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex)
        }
        else -> super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex)
    }
}

override fun onDataChanged() {
    hasDragged = false
}
```

I may be doing something wrong, but it seemed that [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38291210/333525) above code duplicated effort since the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and the observable snapshots will automagically update on notification. This caused the drag to end abruptly with new values. I was also getting wrong order numbers (probably my fault) by using getSnapshots().get(pos) (snapshots[fromPos] in kotlin). This caused some really weird animations. Also when notifying on the move, I had to reverse the to/from (target/viewHolder) positions. However, please note this does rely on ordering in the query using the order field. And finally, I don't want to let the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter#onChildChanged method to call if it's because of a user drag, that also causes unwanted animation and duplicated effort.

Answer (score 1):

Here I post solution that worked for me. It's based on @prodaea's answer, which has right approach but is not fully functional. It's missing firebase database update and additional check against ChangeEventType.CHANGED to avoid the animation interruption when firebase updates.

Code lives inside adapter which extends `FirebaseRcyclerAdapter` and implements interface with a single method `onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean`:

```
override fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean {

    snapshots[fromPosition].sort = toPosition.toDouble()
    snapshots[toPosition].sort = fromPosition.toDouble()

    // update recycler locally to complete the animation
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)

    updateFirebase(fromPosition, toPosition)

    return true
}

private fun updateFirebase(fromPos: Int, toPos: Int) {

    // flag which prevents callbacks from interrupting the drag animation when firebase database updates
    hasDragged = true

    val firstPath = getRef(fromPos).getPath()
    val secondPath = getRef(toPos).getPath()

    Log.d(_tag, "onItemMove: firstPath: $firstPath, secondPath: $secondPath")
    val updates = mapOf(
            Pair(firstPath + "/sort", snapshots[fromPos].sort),
            Pair(secondPath + "/sort", snapshots[toPos].sort))
    getRef(fromPos).root.updateChildren(updates)

    Log.d(_tag, "updateFirebase, catA: \"${snapshots[fromPos]}\", catB: \"${snapshots[toPos]}\"")
}

private fun DatabaseReference.getPath() = toString().substring(root.toString().length)

override fun onChildChanged(type: ChangeEventType,
                            snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                            newIndex: Int,
                            oldIndex: Int) {

    Log.d(_tag, "onChildChanged:else, type:$type, new: $newIndex, old: $oldIndex, hasDragged: $hasDragged, snapshot: $snapshot")

    when (type) {
        // avoid the drag animation interruption by checking against 'hasDragged' flag
        ChangeEventType.MOVED -> if (!hasDragged) {
            super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex)
        }
        ChangeEventType.CHANGED -> if (!hasDragged) {
            super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex)
        }
        else -> {
            super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex)
        }
    }
}

override fun onDataChanged() {
    hasDragged = false
    Log.d(_tag, "onDataChanged, hasDragged: $hasDragged")
}
```